# PHP - Change root directory to project root directory

Tags: php, html, server

Im trying to test a project live, everything runs fine but it is fetching scripts from the root of the server i.e

```
servername/123/123/123/project/assets/css/styles.css
```

I need it to fetch scripts from the project directory i.e

```
/assets/css/styles.css
```

Here is the code from the project

```
define('ROOT_PATH', dirname(__FILE__));
define('ROOT_URL', str_replace(rtrim($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'], '/'), '', str_replace(DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, '/', ROOT_PATH)));
```

Comment: Not sure if it's the problem but I'd recommend separating out the two replacements so that `str_replace` isn't within another `str_replace`. That way you can debug each one individually and see what it's evaluating to.

Comment: Guess I have it wrong then, tried removing them and the scripts still being fetched from somewhere. Have to keep looking.

Comment: You haven't asked a question.

Comment: I did ask a question as I believe I had found the code in question, but as stated it seems i was mistaken and will have to delve deeper into this cms code.